# iOS 14 menu picker style's label becomes dim sometimes when changing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I have a `Picker` in my `SwiftUI View` with the new `MenuPickerStyle`.

[image: Menu picker label becomes dim on changing]

As you can see, the label of the picker is same of the options, and it becomes dim when changing from one option to another.

It looks like it is not tappable, but when tapping it does the required job.

Here's my code. It is just a very simple picker implementation.

```
struct MenuPicker: View {
    
    @State var selection: String = "one"
    
    var array: [String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text(selection).frame(width: 100), content: {
            ForEach(array, id: \.self, content: { word in
                Text(word).tag(word)
            })
        })
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        .padding()
        .background(Color(.systemBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            MenuPicker()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug with:

```
public init(selection: Binding<SelectionValue>, label: Label, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

You can try replacing it with:

```
public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, selection: Binding<SelectionValue>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

---

Here is a workaround (you can only use `String` as the label):

```
Picker(selection, selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(array, id: \.self) { word in
        Text(word).tag(word)
    }
}
.frame(width: 100)
.animation(nil)
.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

Comment: Great finding!. I'm filing a radar for that initializer.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the other initializer or workaround are working for me, but at least we can confirm it's a bug. @Imthath can you post the radar link so I can second it?

Comment: @benpva16 I don't know how to share the radar link. Here's the feedback assistant ID for the issue I've submitted- FB8888712.